# qmail throws error "CNAME_­lookup_­failed_­temporarily"

Tags: email

I am using Qmail and when I am sending mails I am sometimes getting the bellow error in my log for a particular domain.

Jun 22 05:20:47 221832-web1 qmail: 1308738047.397431 delivery 1040373: deferral: CNAME_lookup_failed_temporarily._(#4.4.3)/

Can anyone please tell me what are the factors responsible for such error ?

What are the DNS requests sent by Qmail when sending an email ?

FYI: The patch for the DNS cache size issue is already included in Qmail.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?  In your qmail logs, or in your DNS logs?  Can you include the entire log message in your question?

Comment: @Flimzy, I am getting this error in my qmail log. I have edit the post to include the entire error message.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is in the qmail FAQ document that came in the package.  It's question 2.5, telling you that a temporary deferral is exactly that — only temporary and merely a deferral.

Sometimes this error repeats itself indefinitely until the deferred mail times out of the queue and bounces as unsendable.  This is the result of a qmail bodge to work around a common software bug in the 1990s and an incorrectly sized buffer.

In 1996 Dan Bernstein modified qmail to work around a bug in BIND version 4.  The way that it does this workaround can cause temporary DNS lookup failures.  [It is possible to remove this bodge, restoring the original qmail behaviour and averting the effects of the bodge, as long as one is aware of the negative interaction with BIND version 4](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/qmail/#any-to-cname) and with dnscache ([which doesn't cache `CNAME` lookups and also has to be fixed](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/djbdns/#dnscache-cname-handling)).

Another consequence of the bodge, that is mostly averted by reverting to the original qmail behaviour, is that responses from a local proxy DNS server to `qmail-remote` can sometimes need to be larger than the 512 octet DNS/UDP packet size.  There are [qmail patches to use a properly sized response buffer for DNS lookups](http://ckdhr.com/ckd/qmail-103.patch) in such use circumstances.  Reverting to using `CNAME` queries instead of `ANY` queries mitigates this, however, as it is often the extraneous resource records that `qmail-remote` has no real interest in that are causing the responses to exceed 512 octets in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I came to know from my DNS provider that they had a DDOS attack on their DNS servers and this is the cause of the error. It is fixed now.